# Robocopy: check If file exist before execution

Tags: robocopy

I'm using Robocopy.
What commands do I need in my batch file so that if a file exists, then continue?

File: "c:\users\test\sample.txt"

If the file exists, then continue

How would I go about doing this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to quit if the file doesn't exist and copy it if it does, you could try the following:

```
if not exist c:\users\test\sample.txt exit 2
robocopy c:\users\test\ c:some\destination\directory\ sample.txt
```

If you wanted to copy if it does exist, and the copy is kind of an optional thing, then remove the `not` and replace `exit 2` with the robocopy.

Comment: Thanks Micron Mushroom for your response. I tried the if exist and used exit 2 and it exited out of the batch file. Is there a way if the condition is met for the script to continue.

Comment: You need to have a `not` before the `exist` for it to exit when the file doesn't exist, then it should work.

Comment: Sorry. I've tried if exits and if not exist both exit the batch file. Is there another command I can use beside exit for the batch file to continue?.